# how can i sort firebase timestamp data reverse reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When I create new note, it orders old to new, but I want to order new to old (reverse it).
How can i do this ?

my codes:

```
const notesRef = useFirestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection("notes");
  const {status, data} = useFirestoreCollection(notesRef.orderBy("timezone"));
```

and its image: (Here, it order like 1-2-3, but i want to order, 3-2-1, new to old)
[image]

our return like map:

```
 {data?.docs?.map((d, index) => {
              return (<Note
                      key={index}
                      id={index}
                      title={d.data().title}
                      content={d.data().content}
                      onDelete={deleteNote}
                      onDocId={d.id}
                      timezone={d.data().timezone}
                    />);
            })}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sort a query in descending order, you can pass a second parameter to `orderBy`. So:

```
notesRef.orderBy("timezone", "desc")
```

Also see the Firebase documentation on [ordering data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data).

Answer (score 1):

There are a bunch of ways of doing this.

- Fetch the data in reversed order from firebase. I am using 25 as an example. You can choose the limit as per your requirements.

```
notesRef.orderBy("timezone").limitToLast(25);
```

- Reverse the data on the client-side

```
const {status, data} = useFirestoreCollection(notesRef.orderBy("timezone"));
console.log(data.docs.reverse())
```

Comment: what is the limitToLast value?

Comment: i tried to limitToLast(10), but it didn't work. Also I have a map (I added above), and i add data?.reverse() function, but it also didn't work

Comment: you can look at the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#limittolast

Comment: i have updated my answer after looking at the data. you can reverse the data.docs array.

Comment: thanks a lot. Also look other answer, if i write "desc" near the timezone, it also work.
But doc.reverse() also work. <3